# How much space does a class take in the JVM?

Tags: java, memory, classloader

I've been looking to no avail searching different sites because all the search results want to tell me how to compute the size of an object, not of a class.

When we define a class (with a .class file in a jar/war) and it gets loaded into the JVM, how much space does that take up? Obviously it depends on the actual things in the class, a class with more fields has more metadata to store. But if we say for example the class had 10 integer fields and 10 reference fields to other objects:

- How much extra space would it take up in the JVM to have say, 1,000 of those classes (all extending the same base class)?
- Would it change if they were anonymous classes instead of defined classes?

Comment: It's unlikely that this is of general interest because classes usually have information that can't grow (that is, even though an instance of a class may include an array, which may grow large, the class itself doesn't grow), and the number of classes is usually an order of magnitude less than the number of objects. So it's generally negligible in modern memory terms.

Answer (score 1):

Well every `Class` itself is an object. So an indicative size would be to call `Instrumentation.getObjectSize()` on the class itself.

You can follow the tutorial here: 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-size-of-object

And then if you want to check the size of `MyClass` you can do:
`InstrumentationAgent.getObjectSize(MyClass.getClass());`

This doesn't mean it is the only memory associated with this class, because the class loader, garbage collector and other internal workings of the JVM might keep other meta information about the class.

Comment: Sooooo the only real way would be to like... get a baseline reading of JVM memory usage and then load in the 1000 classes and see how big it gets... I was really hoping some random dude had already done that and posted their results on a blog somewhere with some observations and conclusions. :-p

Comment: Well probably if you look hard enough you might find something. But it is not something people usually care about that much. Because the Class Loader usually is smart enough to only load a class when needed. The issues people have usually are more related to how many instances of that class are created, and the overheads of creating them and disposing of them. The file size of the class file itself is another indication of size. Maybe an explanation of what you are trying to solve would be more helpful for people to give you the right answer.

Comment: @corsiKa those memory values can difference greatly between operation systems, and the contents of your class

Answer (score 0):

The answer will most definitely depend on JVM implementation (including version of such implementation, platform etc). There is no one number you can get.

As for anonymous inner classes, these still have class names generated for them, so this should have zero impact.